# How to over write salesforce standard exception message in catch block?

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception

I am using

```
 catch (Exception e){ 
   ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'my error msg'); 
   ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
}
```

And have `<apex:pageMessages/>` in my VF page.

still i get my custom message  + the salesforce standard exception displayed at my page. I want only my message to be shown.

For comment

```
catch(Exception e){
     if(validateVariable.contains('STRING_TOO_LONG') &&
          validateVariable.contains('data value too large') ) { 
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Character limit exceeded. Please limit your essay in the prescribed character limit'); 
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
       }
```

Comment: can you add your dml statement code. Is it inside try or not? one more thing sounds like you are using 2 `<apex:pageMessages/>` in your VF page

Comment: Its a text field , i have put some character limit on it . And i want my custom error message should be thrown instead of the standard salesforce one.

Comment: how many `<apex:pageMessages/>` tag you are using in your page?

Comment: Only 1 <apex:pageMessages/> is there

Comment: Could you also include the part in your code where the error is occurring.

Comment: catch(Exception e){
if(validateVariable.contains('STRING_TOO_LONG') && validateVariable.contains('data value too large') )
                  {
                    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Character limit exceeded. Please limit your essay in the prescribed character limit'); 
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
                  }

Comment: validateVariable =e.getMessage()

Comment: I saw this help post and followed it, but still no help. 

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000050990&language=en_US

Comment: The code you posted here looks fine. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @user27072 If you add your completed part of code where you are performing DML, where you are adding apex page message  and where you are showing page message (i.e. `<apex:pageMessages/>` ) then we can understand the problem. It will be very helpful for us to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate way to handle this is by creating a [custom exception](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm) that gets thrown as an inner exception using a utility class. You first catch the exception, then rethrow it, catching it with your custom "inner exception" that produces the error message you'd like to send. Here's an example from the documentation:

```
public class MerchandiseException extends Exception {}

public class MerchandiseUtility {
    public static void mainProcessing() {
        try {
            insertMerchandise();
        } catch(MerchandiseException me) {
            System.debug('Message: ' + me.getMessage());    
            System.debug('Cause: ' + me.getCause());    
            System.debug('Line number: ' + me.getLineNumber());    
            System.debug('Stack trace: ' + me.getStackTraceString());    
        }
    }

    public static void insertMerchandise() {
        try {
            // Insert merchandise without required fields
            Merchandise__c m = new Merchandise__c();
            insert m;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            // Something happened that prevents the insertion
            // of Employee custom objects, so throw a more
            // specific exception.
            throw new MerchandiseException(
                'Merchandise item could not be inserted.', e);
        }
    }
}
```